# Deploying Visual Web Parts (not Sandboxed) by Uploading

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a visual web part to be deployed in farm. **Not sandboxed**. But when i try to deploy it by **uploading as a solution**, it says only sandboxed web parts can be activated.

Is there a way to upload and deploy such web parts **without using commands**?

Comment: Are you trying Powershell script to deploy the solutions? Or directly from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Pro.. Thanx for the responce. Powershell and deploying thru VS is working. But as I need to deliver the packaged solution, the user should not be involved with technical stuff. Is it possible to deploy it by uploading the .wsp file?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse you can deploy the packaged solution (.WSP file). So did you try to activate the feature by uploading WSP file?

Comment: I did upload. But when I try to activate it, it throws an error saying that only sandboxed solutions can activate, so I couldn't proceed with deploying.